# Jest - Get the generic mock for a file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

In Jest you can use the method 
`jest.genMockFromModule('fs')` to get the generic mock for a *module* and change its methods. But if I try to run this for a file, i.e., `"../app/helper.js"`, it says it can't find the module.

Is this method only for finding *modules*? If so, is there a way to find the generic mock for a file?

Comment: Is your wanted mocked file located one directory above your test?

Comment: That is a fair assumption

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your test code and the exact error output?

Comment: Is the mock file inside the __mocks__ directory one directory above your __tests__ directory?

Comment: Can you post your directory structure and the code where you are trying to use `fs`